# How do I make Grails application.yml make use of environments specific entries if they are already defined in the yml root?

Tags: grails, configuration-files

In Grails 3 I want to use an application.yml file with environment specific blocks (http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#environments). We have a generic/root configuration, and for each of environment we want to overload certain properties. In the Spring boot world we would have for example an application.properties file, and an application-test.properties file. Spring Boot would load the files in such order that environment specific values trump general ones, based on the load order (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). 
But when I try in a Grails app, the order seems like "if it is defined in the yml root, do not even think about looking for it in the environment block".
I really really would like to avoid copying about 50 properties from root in all our 6 environment blocks. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment specific yml files e.g.

```
grails-app/
    conf/
        application.yml
        application-development.yml
        application-production.yml
```

Comment: have you tried that with a variable defined in both yml files, under Grails 3.1? When I was trying it seemed to ignore the specific yml.